# PHP If Else with exit not working

Tags: php, json, phpexcel

I dont know what's wrong with my code but it's not working im working with phpexcel to get data from excel file and to parse it to JSON object and there's no problem with that my problem is to filter if there's no more data on excel file to read then the json data will print and to exit the current script, but sometimes the if else works sometimes not it look likes the if statement was ignored and skipped.

```
if (empty($csDlvSked) === true || isset($csDlvSked) === false) {
       print json_encode($jsonData);
       exit();
   }
else {
     //To read excel data sample:
   $result .= array("data1" => $data1, "data2" => $data2);
   $jsonData[] = $result;
   }
```

Comment: it will be empty if not set

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isset($csDlvSked)) {
       print json_encode($jsonData);
       exit();
   }
else {
     //To read excel data sample:
   $result .= array("data1" => $data1, "data2" => $data2);
   $jsonData[] = $result;
   }
```

Comment: hey. appreciate your help but it's not working but I managed to filter other variable for exiting the whole script. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian Can you explain your answer.